# How to skip a folder and its sub-folder and files from getting deleted using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have a PS script which deletes the folders and files from a particular path older than 15 days.
I want to exclude "_tasks" folder and its contents from getting deleted but the scripts deletes the files and folders inside it even when I have provided -Exclude property to exclude _tasks folder and its contents.

Below is the script I am using.

How can I exclude the _tasks folder and its sub-folders and files from getting deleted?

> Get-ChildItem –Path "F:\Suraj\Garbage" -Recurse -Exclude "__tasks" |
> Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15))} |
> Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

Below images shows that the files on the left side were deleted inside the _tasks folders. I don't want them to be deleted. Any suggestion for same would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code selects all files except folder _task and its subfolders..

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'F:\Suraj\Garbage' -Recurse  | 
Select-Object  LastWriteTime -ExpandProperty FullName |
Where-Object { ($_ -notlike 'F:\Suraj\Garbage\_tasks*') -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15))} |
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

or better like Theo's suggest:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'F:\Suraj\Garbage' -Recurse  | 
Where-Object { ($_.FullName -notlike 'F:\Suraj\Garbage\_tasks*') -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15))} |
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: Frenchy,  thanks for the reply. Tried your code and yes its not deleting the content of _Tasks folder but however, it is deleting the other folders and files which are present at the same path where _tasks folder is present even though they are not 15 days older. How can avoid that issue now?

Comment: Better remove the `Select-Object` line all together and change the `Where-Object` line to `Where-Object { ($_.FullName -notlike 'F:\Suraj\Garbage\_tasks*') -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15).Date)} | ...`. By using `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`, you will **lose** other properties like `LastWriteTime`

Comment: its just paste error,  add LastWriteTime in select-object see my edited answer